# How to make external api call more efficient

Tags: system-design

I’m building a shipment tracking system. I have an external service that I can make an API call to get the shipment status. Whenever a shipment status changed, I wanna get notified.

What would be the most efficient way to call the external api to check the status of the shipments? Imagine I have 1 million shipments to track.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to set up a [webhook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webhook) from the external service to your server. When a shipment changes status, the external API should call an endpoint on your server. This is a very common practice for use cases like yours where statuses change and you need to be notified.

Otherwise, you'll just have to poll the API periodically. I'd suggest fitting your calls to the expected pattern of status updates (e.g. if a shipment typically takes a minimum of 2 days to update, then wait 2 days before checking for a status update)

Comment: Polling can be reduced by consolidating requests. Include a list of all shipments you want the status for so you only need a single request and response. Caching might be another option if you can't do consolidation. If request rate is very high (several single per second) but you can tolerate more latency, a caching server can group requests and send them off every e.g. 1 second, 10 seconds, etc.